# How to merge 2 Dictionaries into a third that consists of {Key=Value(Dict1), Value=Value(Dict2)}

Tags: c#, dictionary, merge

I am trying to merge 2 Dictionaries.

The first one consists of an ID and a Title, so for instance: {2, Error}.

The second one consists of an ID and the frequency in which the ID occurs: {2, 3}.

I want to create a dictionary that looks like this:  {Error, 3}.

Is this possible?

My code thus far works only if there are no duplicates ... I want to just add the frequency number of the duplicate ID to the already saved frequency of the previous occurrence of the same ID. So e.g. if in dict2 for some reason there exists {2, 3} and {2, 5} the result in dict3 should be {Error, 8}.

```
foreach (var item in dict2)
{
    foreach(var entry in dict1)
    {
        if (item.Key.Equals(entry.Key))
        {
            dict3.Add(entry.Value.ToString(), (int)item.Value);                       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code to show us what you tried

Comment: Not that this might be risky given that there's no built-in guarantee that Title will be unique, so you'll have to make sure your titles are unique before you do this).

Comment: Titles are not unuiqe.

Comment: You can't have `{2, 3}` and `{2, 5}`. Those are duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var combinedDictQry =
    from entry1 in dictionary1
    from entry2 in dictionary2
    where entry1.Key == entry2.Key
    select new { Key = entry1.Value, Value = entry2.Value };
var combinedDict = combinedDictQry.ToDictonary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

This will serve you well for smaller dictionaries (ie. for most practical purposes). If you need to process larger amounts of data, you might get performance issues and you will have to access the values of the second dictionary with `TryGetValue` to make use of the dictionary's better access performance.

If you expect duplicate values in `dictionary1`, `.ToDictionary` will not work, because duplicate keys are not allowed in a dictionary. You can however create a lookup. Duplicate keys will be merged and the values can be enumerated:

```
var combinedLookup = combinedDictQry.ToLookup(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

Comment: That was a remarkably fast response, thank you :)
How will this code handle duplicates?

Comment: @Maetness It will throw an `ArgumentExcption`: [Enumerable.ToDictionary Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Sefe that doesn't seem to be the behavior described in the documentation (see my previous comment). Documentation is known to be wrong sometimes but its seem it will throw if a duplicate key is found.

Comment: If you wight encounter duplicate kes, use `.ToLookup` instead of `.ToDictionary`.

Comment: @InBetween: The original comment is ambiguous, I referred to the possibility of duplicate keys in the input data.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems quite possible to find duplicates, because you are not mapping key to key; its a value to key so duplicate keys is something to consider. Whats not clear is if the OP wants a LookUp or  the first encountered value, the last, whatever. Underspecified.

Comment: .ToDictionary throws an Error, .ToLookup returns a result in the form of Key="Error".

Comment: If you want the valus of the lookup, you have to iterate it with `foreach`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bunch!